# How to resize window and views when porting from iPhone to iPad?

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios

I am porting my iPhone app to the iPad (I did  a straight copy of the iPhone code, renamed it, and set the mainwindow.xib size to iPhone/iPod).

I don't see anything that will allow me to resize the newly renamed app to iPad.  How do I do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently it can't be easily done.  I gave up and re-wrote the app.